# Why session not start on login in CI

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, session

Why session not start on login in CI, i entered right credential whenever i entered wrong cred. it shows an error that's "Wrong username and password"

Here is my code:

```
if(($result_data->user_email==$username)&&($password_enc==$result_data->user_pass)){ 
    $this->load->model('password','password');
    $role=$this->password->get_user_details($result_data->user_email);
    $user_status=$role->user_status;
    $user_status = intval($user_status);
    //var_dump($user_status);
    if($user_status==1){
    @session_start();
    //$_SESSION['admin_id']=$row[0]->ID;

    $_SESSION['admin_id']=1;
    echo $_SESSION['admin_id'];
    $_SESSION['role']=$role->role;
    $_SESSION['main_id']=$role->ID;
} else {
    echo 1;
    //die();
}
```

Comment: what makes you think it's not starting?

Comment: there is a thing called documentation - if you start learning a framework i strongly suggest to read it because it'll make your life easier... Take a look @ https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution for your problem :

**Set Session :**

```
$this->load->library('session');

if($user_status==1){
   $this->session->set_userdata(array(
    'admin_id'  => 1,
    'role' => $role->role,
    'main_id'  => $role->ID,
  ));
}
```

**Get Session value :**

```
echo $this->session->userdata('admin_id');
echo $this->session->userdata('role');
echo $this->session->userdata('main_id');
```

I hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

You are using core php for session storage instead of the codeigniter session. You must have to load session library. I give you full code of create and delete the session in proper way. You have to add this code and use it as you want(because i give unset as well). Try like this:

```
<?php
//load session library
$this->load->library('session');
// set array of items in session
$arraydata = array(
        'admin_id'  => 1,
        'role'=> $role->role,
        'main_id'=>$role->ID
);
$this->session->set_userdata($arraydata);

/**** GET SESSION DATA ****/
echo "Admin id: ". $this->session->userdata('admin_id');
echo "Role: ". $this->session->userdata('role');
echo "Main id: " . $this->session->userdata('main_id');

// get e'thing stored in session at once
echo '<pre>';
print_r($this->session->userdata());

/**** REMOVE SESSION DATA ****/
// unset specific key from session
$this->session->unset_userdata('admin_id');
$this->session->unset_userdata('role');
$this->session->unset_userdata('main_id');

// unset multiple items at once
$keys = array('admin_id', 'role','main_id');
$this->session->unset_userdata($keys);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($this->session->userdata());
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $array = array(
        'admin_id'  => 1,
        'role'=> $role->role,
        'main_id'=>$role->ID
    );  
  $this->session->set_userdata($array);

  echo $this->session->userdata('admin_id');
```